# Expresso Store Test Mode Error

Tags: expresso-store

I am testing Expresso Store with Authorize.net. I have the API login ID and Transaction key entered in correctly but I am receiving the following error:

ERROR: (TESTMODE) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

I contacted Authorize.et and they said to make sure that we are posting request to the correct URL and provided this link: https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A415&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1450803628869

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Store and EE are you using? Authorize.net also offers two different gateway types SIM (off-site) or AIM (on-site) which version are you trying to use? Also there are settings for Test Mode and Developer Mode how are those configured?

Comment: Having said that when I have run into this issue it has always been the result of how Authorize.net approves/provisions test accounts. They have multiple different endpoint urls based upon your account type, who/how you signed up, and what type of test account your requested. Store submits to `https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll` with Developer Mode set to False. and `https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll` when Developer mode is set to True. You can see it in `store/vendor/omnipay/authorizenet/src/Message/AbstractRequest.php` around 10.

Comment: I am using live credentials with authorize.net set to test mode. In Store I have test mode and developer mode set to on. Should I just set developer mode to off for my testing purposes or do I need to set up a sandbox account with authorize.net?

Comment: Turn off Developer mode if you have not setup a sandbox account. Developer mode requires different login credentials then your live account that you would need to create at developer.authorize.net. It is very confusing that they have both test mode and live mode in both account types.

Comment: That was it. Thank you for the quick replies!!

Comment: Cool I will move it to an answer with a bit more details for people in the future.